# Business Objects XI link to report

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Does anyone know how if there is a way to link to a Folder or Report contained in Business Objects Enterprise? I would like to add a link on my intranet web site to a Report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can link to a report using [Url Reporting](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_java_dg_doc/doc/boesdk_java_dg/Report_Linking.html).  If you want to enumerate an BusinessObject Enterprise folder's contents, you will need to use the BusinessObjects SDK.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That documentation got me really close. I am just trying to figure out some authentication issues now. When i use opendocument.jsp the site does a single sign on that changes the query string parameters.

Comment: Don't forget with the openDcoument call to use the WCAToken. This will not create additional sessions.